# Avada 5.0 Wordpress. Button inside container is not centering

Tags: html, css, wordpress, shortcode

I have tryed to center this button "get in touch" on chris-tanner.com through avada 5.0, is there a way to do it through shortcode or is it a must to use custom css?

Thanks
Chris Tanner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to apply `text-align: center;` to its parent like below

```
#main .fullwidth-box .fusion-row{
      text-align: center;
}
```

[image]

but make sure you atleast post some code or create online demo of your problem  as direct link to site is not recommended

Comment: thanks, was just not sure how to do a online demo with wp. just used a direct link as this is my test domain.

Answer (score 0):

Please apply below css.

```
.fusion-layout-column .fusion-column-content-centered {
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
}
```